# Flexbox have max-width and max-height content and still be responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with 4 columns, and an image in the first one.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y62zt4sv/6/)

I want it so the image is responsive (which works), but I'd like it once the screen gets bigger and it's no longer shrinking/expanding, to have a max-width in pixels, instead of a percentage.

I used `max-width: 100%;` to make it responsive, but once the screen get's big enough where it's not shrinking or expanding, I'd like it to have a `max-width: 250px;`, so it doesn't continue to grow.

If I get rid of the `100%` and change it to `250px`, it's no longer responsive when the screen gets small.

I don't want to do a media query because I want it to work for an image.

Is there anyway to do this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/9d/db/c7/9ddbc7c118bcd047a06b44bae34bb413--exotic-flowers-tropical-flowers.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      This is a group of flex columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Isn't that interesting?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: -30px;
  padding: 15px 0 60px;
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left:30px;
  padding-right:30px;
  min-width: 0;
}

.col img {
  width: auto;
  max-width:100%;
  // max-width: 250px; // This breaks it, but is what I need
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to set the `max-width: 250px` to your first `.col`

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8k25rrtg/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: -30px;
  padding: 15px 0 60px;
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left:30px;
  padding-right:30px;
  min-width: 0;
}

.col img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.col:first-child {
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/9d/db/c7/9ddbc7c118bcd047a06b44bae34bb413--exotic-flowers-tropical-flowers.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      This is a group of flex columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Isn't that interesting?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another option is to wrap the `img` in a `span` and give the `span` the `max-width: 250px`

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8k25rrtg/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin-left: -30px;
  margin-right: -30px;
  padding: 15px 0 60px;
}
.col {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left:30px;
  padding-right:30px;
  min-width: 0;
}
.col img { 
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 250px;
}
.col span { 
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <span>
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/9d/db/c7/9ddbc7c118bcd047a06b44bae34bb413--exotic-flowers-tropical-flowers.jpg" />
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      This is a group of flex columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Isn't that interesting?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```